# Error: 'Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:NameSpace.Properties}Settings'.'

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, application-settings, wpf-style

I define my settings and styles in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:Kavand.UI.Properties">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <properties:Settings x:Key="settings" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style x:Key="PopupMenu_StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource settings}, Path=Default.Font_Menu_Size}" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource settings}, Path=Default.Font_Menu_Family}" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource settings}, Path=Default.Font_Menu_Weight}" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource KavandMenuItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource K_Brush_Gray}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When I run my application, I get the error:

> 'Cannot create unknown type
>   '{clr-namespace:Kavand.UI.Properties}Settings'.'
>   Line number '6' and line position
>   '14'.

Comment: Is it a compile error or a runtime error? Does removing the first three setters allow the application to run?

Comment: It is a runtime error, no, just when I remove section that contains definition, application will be compiled

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I had set the file's "Build Action" property to "Resource". When I changed it to "Page" the problem was resolved.

Comment: Waaat? This worked for me too. But the documentation explicitly says to make sure your resource dictionaries have "Resource" build actions.

Answer (score 51):

Keep your "Build Action" property to "Resource" and just change this row:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:Kavand.UI.Properties"
```

with this:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:Kavand.UI.Properties;assembly=Kavand.UI"
```

Comment: I set the build action back to Resource and it worked even without the namespace change. Gaaah! This problem is so fickle. What is up with Visual Studio?

Comment: Anyone knows when to use Resource and when to use Page? In some other articles using Resource was recommended to solve other mysterious behaviour of user control libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Just posting another potential solution, because i just recently stumbled over this exception.

It could be that your referenced class-cefinition (in your case `Kavand.UI.Properties.Settings`) does not use `public`-access-modifier.

**So in my case i could solve this problem by writing `public` before the class definition.**

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem I had that lead me to this question. My class was "internal". Changing it to "public" solved my issue. +1

Answer (score 3):

As a variation on other answers & comments, this worked for me:

- Set the file's "Build Action" property to "Page".
- Build (problem gone - but...)
- Set the file's "Build Action" property to "Resource".
- Build
- Problem still gone!

Seems like a VS bug to me.