# WPF dynamically load xaml with validation rules

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I am relatively new in WPF and I face a problem.
I have to implement a form that gets the UI(xaml) from the database (as also the data). 
Each of these forms that will be created at runtime they will have different controls.
Although I disagree with this approach I have to follow my boss directions.
The problem is with the validation.
We decided to do it with Validation Rules.
So I tried to implemented the basic example with the [AgeRangeRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50" FontSize="15"
     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
     Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
     Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Age" Source="{StaticResource ods}"
         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
       <Binding.ValidationRules>
         <c:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

The error that I get when I load the xaml is

```
Additional information: 'Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:WpfDynamicTest1}AgeRangeRule'.'
```

And is in this line:

```
 <c:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
```

Note: c is defined as:

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfDynamicTest1"
```

How can I overcome this error?
I faced similar errors with the ControlTemplate and Style for the errors but I moved them to the Application.xaml and my problems solved.
Can I do something similar with the reference to the class?

**Edit: Additional Info:**
How I load the xaml:
The "cell" form has these properties:

```
 Public Property FormId() As Integer
    Get
        Return miFormId
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        miFormId = value
        FormCharacteristics(value)
    End Set
End Property

 Public Property UI() As String
    Get
        Return msUI
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        msUI = value
        Dim rootObject As DependencyObject = XamlReader.Parse(value)
        Me.Content = rootObject
    End Set
End Property
```

So when I call the form I do this:

```
 Dim winD As New winDynamic
 winD.FormId = 4
 winD.Show()
```

The FormCharacteristics fills msUI and UI is loaded.

Comment: Are you sure that you ValidationRule "AgeRangeRule " is correctly defined in namespace named WpfDynamicTest1 ?

Comment: Yes, if I don't load the xaml from DB at runtime and have it as usual the code is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not sure if you search through some of the following links but i hope they could be of help to you:

[Compile/Execute XAML during program runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003183/compile-execute-xaml-during-program-runtime)

[WPF – dynamically compile and run event handlers within loose XAML using CodeDom](http://elegantcode.com/2010/12/21/wpf-dynamically-compile-and-run-event-handlers-within-loose-xaml-using-codedom/)

[Loading XAML at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910814/loading-xaml-at-runtime)

[Error: 'Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:NameSpace.Properties}Settings'.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156723/error-cannot-create-unknown-type-clr-namespacenamespace-propertiessettings)

**EDIT**

Based on the links above, assuming you are using XamlReader, I created a sample and its working fine. In this case, the reason I found is, the XAML Parser need the [ParserContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.parsercontext(v=vs.110).aspx) to map the namespaces to bind the required types at run time.

**Xaml (Dynamic usercontrol to load)**

```
<UserControl 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300" Width="300"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <c:MyDataSource x:Key="ods"/>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                              Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50" FontSize="15"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
         Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Age" Source="{StaticResource ods}"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <c:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <Button x:Name="btnDynamic" Width="150" Height="30" Content="Click Me"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind (C#)**

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadXAML();
        }

        public void LoadXAML()
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader xamlStream = new StreamReader(@"C:\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\DynamicWindow.xaml"))
                {
                    var context = new ParserContext();
                    context.XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[] { });
                    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("c", "clr-namespace:WpfApplication1");
                    context.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("clr-namespace:WpfApplication1", "WpfApplication1", "WpfApplication1");

                    string xamlString = xamlStream .ReadToEnd();

                    DependencyObject rootObject = XamlReader.Parse(xamlString, context) as DependencyObject;
                    cntControl.Content = rootObject; //cntControl is a content control I placed inside MainWindow
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note**

For the Binding Validation., I used same [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx) code you provided.

Also since I am not with the VB.NET HAT now, I choose C# for the code behind!! Though the code is simple enough.

Comment: @Nianios What happen if you change: xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfDynamicTest1" To xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfDynamicTest1;assembly:WpfDynamicTest1OrWhatEverAssemblyItIsIn"

Comment: Hm, I code in VB and when I add this I get a lot of errors. The first one is The URI "clr-namespace:BindValidation;assembly:BindValidation" is not a valid namespace identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your AngeRangeRule should derive from ValidationRule.

`public class AgeRangeRule : ValidationRule
    {
     ....
    }`

And you have to override `ValidationResult` member:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        // Cast value object and check if it is valid
        return new ValidationResult(...,...);
    }
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question. I followed the example. SO I did all these. Now I am trying to load the xaml at runtime.

Comment: Strange. I indeed tried to have a class `AgeRangeRule` and I got the error that you had. And when I derive it from `ValidationRule` and implemented the `Validate`, your code sample ran fine.

Comment: So are you saying that you are load the xaml at runtime and it works? Because mine is running fine when I don't load the xaml at runtime , but not when I load it at runtime